# Why can't I copy-paste from PyCharm into Maya Script Editor?

Tags: pycharm, copy-paste, maya

I can copy-paste code from Notepad++ into Maya Script Editor, and from MSE into Notepad++. I can copy-paste from MSE into PyCharm. But I can't paste from PyCharm into MSE, even if I "Copy as Plain Text".

Why not, and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with Maya's implementation of QT interacting with PyCharm's cut and paste. Unfortunately there is no simple fix for maya 2010-2016.

You can use the [Charcoal editor](http://zurbrigg.com/charcoal-editor) plugin to replace your script editor -- it supports rich text properly. Or you can use [MayaCharm](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?5280-MayaCharm) to execute code in Maya directly from pycharm

Answer (score 1):

As theodox said, its because of how Qt is implemented by Maya.

That aside,
There is a work around which I use for that. Works great. Called [PureText](http://stevemiller.net/puretext/). Its Windows only though. Once you copy text from PyCharm, paste it into Maya Script Editor with "Win + V" (Default Puretext shortcut key).

Cheers!